# Route native Alsa app audio to bluetooth speaker with Pulseaudio?

Tags: bluetooth, alsa, pulseaudio

I have an app that only supports Alsa, and I want to route its audio to a Bluetooth speaker.  I'm attempting to use Pulseaudio to do it if that is possible.

The Bluetooth speaker is paired and I can play system audio to it.  The app in question only lists hardware playback devices per what is shown in *aplay -l* and I'm using plughw0,0 bcm2835 ALSA.  Pulseaudio doesn't seem to see the playback, so I can't route the audio anywhere.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 5/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 2: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1 [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`pactl list sinks short` only gives me one sink with a default /etc/pulse/default.pa:

```
0   alsa_output.platform-soc_audio.analog-mono  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

Shooting in the dark, I tried editing /etc/pulse/default.pa to include `load-module module-alsa-sink device=plughw:0,0` in which case I see a corresponding sink and monitor source:

```
pactl list sinks short
0   alsa_output.plughw_0_0  module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE

pactl list sources short
0   alsa_output.plughw_0_0.monitor  module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

I see these in pavucontrol, but the corresponding source `Monitor of Built-in Audio` is not seeing any sound from the application.

I might be going about this the wrong way, but I think I should be able to play a monitor of my `plughw0,0 bcm2835 ALSA` on my bluetooth output device.  I also had a quick try doing this with Jack to no avail.

Any ideas would be appreciated.